# How to draw hexagonal shape image in react Native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I am trying to display a hexagon shaped image with white borders.
The problem is, I can't make the view that contains the image hexagonal.

Has anyone ever needed to display such an image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use clipPath and svg

[Medium article](https://medium.com/prototyped/react-native-svg-image-clippath-cf107ee9b812)

Comment: Nice, i'll try
Ty